# iPhone Safari does not redirect to new page with similar URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter, mobile-safari

I'm trying to redirect a user from our Flutter app into safari to make payments. We have two buttons which open in safari. When a user clicks on it, it opens up in safari, the user makes a payment and is redirected back into the app. However, if URL1 was already open and the user goes back to the app and tries to open URL2 , it does not open URL2 in the tab and only refreshes the tab with the old URL (URL1). You can test this by going to the links below on safari.

URL1: https://staging-admin.spotlight.xyz/#/payment/intent/user/7906ab92-31ea-46a4-90f8-d645bedafb46?time=1657808668

URL2: https://staging-admin.spotlight.xyz/#/payment/intent/user/7906ab92-31ea-46a4-90f8-d645bedafb46/org/4c3fbedd-9882-4aeb-8225-6e72c91fadbd?time=1657808709

Here's what I have tried:

- Adding / in the URL instead of ?
- Adding timestamp (like in the example above)

The URL is being served from a nodejs app, if that helps.

EDIT: The code used to open URL is:

```
Future<void> _launchURL(String paymentUrl) async {
    if (await canLaunch(paymentUrl)) {
      await launch(
        paymentUrl,
        forceSafariVC: false,
        enableJavaScript: true,
      );
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $paymentUrl';
    }
  }
```

EDIT2: I updated the url_launcher package to the latest version and launched using the launchUrl function. It still doesn't seem to resolve the issue :(

The URL is being opened in Safari.

```
Future<void> _launchURL(String paymentUrl) async {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(paymentUrl))) {
      await launchUrl(
        Uri.parse(paymentUrl),
        webOnlyWindowName: '_blank',
      );
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $paymentUrl';
    }
  }
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: How do you open urls? Share code.

Answer (score 1):

The two URLs are not so different for the browser, only the hash changes. So, the requested/cached URL would always be https://staging-admin.spotlight.xyz/

You can detect the change in the browser by listening to `hashchange` events.

To invalidate the browser cache / force another request you should move the query string to the correct position, before the hash:

https://staging-admin.spotlight.xyz/?time=1657808668#/payment/intent/user/7906ab92-31ea-46a4-90f8-d645bedafb46

Comment: Nice pickup, seems most likely to be the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this plugin and it's working
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

ScreenShot's

https://prnt.sc/LIjWsToQXsj0

https://prnt.sc/IDIfo_yfQ7Al

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear here whether the URL is being opened in an in-app WebView or in Safari actual.

Given the issue occurs when the user already has URL1 open, I'm assuming the latter. Opening the URL in an in-app WebView might workaround this issue, as the in-app browser will need to be closed before continuing.

Seems as though you are using the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/url_launcher-library.html) package's `launch` function, which has been [deprecated](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/launch.html). Could you try using the newer [`launchUrl`](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/url_launcher/launchUrl.html) function instead?

This function supports a `mode` argument to specify a `LaunchMode`, which defaults to an `inAppWebView` for iOS and Android. This could be changed to `externalApplication` to continue opening in the device's default browser (Safari).